# ActiveMQ doesn't propagate topics on failover reconnection

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm attempting to use a network of brokers that bridges two LANs over a duplex WAN connector:

[image: logical layout of brokers]

- There are actually many subscribers in our setup, each connecting to a different "Broker A", if that makes sense. All of the Broker A instances have their own connections to a single "Broker B".

Software and configurations:

- ActiveMQ 5.14.0, Java 8
- All brokers have non-persistent topics only; advisory messages are on.
- OS: Linux (RHEL 6)

When I initially bring everything online, regardless of the order in which I bring things online, communication between the publisher and subscriber works flawlessly. I've had the system up-and-running for weeks at a time without issue.

What I've observed is that if broker C is restarted, no new topics that show up in broker B ever appear in broker C. New topics are still appearing in broker B as they are created by the subscriber(s). Neither existing nor new topics ever propagate across the WAN to broker C. I've verified this using jconsole.

If I restart broker B, the problem goes away immediately. The topics contained in broker B (according to jconsole) are the same as they were prior to restart, but now they've magically appeared in C.

Brokers B and C have the same configuration (shown below). The only difference is that B creates a duplex network connector to C created using the following code:

```
final NetworkConnector wanNC = new DiscoveryNetworkConnector(
        new URI(String.format("static:(failover:(tcp://%s:%d))", parentNode, port)));
wanNC.setCheckDuplicateMessagesOnDuplex(true);
wanNC.setDecreaseNetworkConsumerPriority(true);
wanNC.setDuplex(true);
wanNC.setName(NetworkUtils.getHostName());
wanNC.setNetworkTTL(10);
wanNC.setSuppressDuplicateTopicSubscriptions(false);

broker.addNetworkConnector(wanNC);
```

broker.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="${broker.id}" start="false"
        offlineDurableSubscriberTimeout="5000" offlineDurableSubscriberTaskSchedule="5000"
        persistent="false" useJmx="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="86400000">

        [...]

        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector name="z-broker-${broker.id}-x-nc"
                decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                networkTTL="10"
                uri="multicast://225.5.5.5:6555?group=TO_X">
                <excludedDestinations>
                    <topic physicalName="X.A" />
                </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
            <networkConnector name="z-broker-${broker.id}-y-nc"
                decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                networkTTL="10"
                uri="multicast://225.5.5.5:6555?group=TO_Y">
                <excludedDestinations>
                    <topic physicalName="X.B.>" />
                </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
        </networkConnectors>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire"
                uri="tcp://${broker.ip}:${broker.port}?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"
                discoveryUri="multicast://225.5.5.5:6555?group=TO_Z" />
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

1. Why don't topics from broker B (existing or new) ever show up in broker C?
2. Why does restarting broker B solve the issue immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the trick was changing the network connector URI from

```
static:(failover:(tcp://<ip>:<port>))
```

to

```
static:(tcp://<ip>:<port>)
```

I didn't need failover transport for any reason since the connection is intended as a network bridge and there's a single remote address.

For whatever reason, using failover prevented topics from propagating on reconnect.